# Blank error while using load objects in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, import

I'm trying to load data from an excel file to a feature class using load objects. After matching all the fields I get the following blank error and no data is added to the feature class. Does anyone know what this error means?

[image]

Comment: Hey Omega - I have no information on this error, maybe check your excel sheet and try again? Do any of the field names in the excel sheet contain spaces or special characters? For loading data, I tend to adjust any "Field Names" to "Field_Names" etc. before attempting the Load Data task.

Comment: do you have any xls data that successfully loads?  If you could post the header and first line (screenshot) in your original question. Maybe also a screenshot of the matched fields?

Comment: Try to use the Append tool.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Jim](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147962/blank-error-while-using-load-objects-in-arcmap-10-2#comment216129_147962) I went back and adjusted all the field names by removing the spaces between and was able to load the data without any problem.